# Adding HTML elements at runtime in JQuery - Not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm adding the HTML elements in runtime by AJAX call from Javascript file.

I want to use combo-box drop down element to show the list of datas. To acheive this, I'm trying like below in my script file.

```
    $("#myList").append("<select id=\"mlist\" >");

    for(var i=0;i<datas.length;i++){
        $("#myList").append("<option>"+datas[i]+"</option>");
     }

    $("#myList").append("</select>");
```

But in the browser, it shows the elements generated as

```
<select id="mlist"> </select>
 <option>INDIA</option>
 <option>CHINA</option>
  <option>JAPAN</option>
```

I want the options to be inserted in between to the select element. Anyone kindly suggest me where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you do it..You need to find the already appended `<select>` and then append to it.

```
var slct =  $("#myList").append("<select id='mlist' />").find('#mlist'); // append the select and find it
for(var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
    slct.append("<option />", { text: datas[i] }); // now append
}
```

Comment: Good, it's much faster to move the jquery select outside the loop and use a temporary variable (slct).

Comment: @CarlJohn glad to have helped :)

Comment: If I want to append the same drop down box element in next row, after inserting some label means, shall i still use append method?

Answer (score 0):

When you append an element it is closed automatically, so you don't need the second `append()` to add the closing tag.

Also, you need to append your `option` elements to the `select`, not `#myList`. Try this:

```
var $select = $("<select />", { id: 'mlist' }).appendTo('#myList');
for (var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
    $select.append($('<option />', { text: datas[i] }));
}
```